# Optimization of an MSSQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Briefly I would like to explain my project.

I have already built an eCommerce website (ASP.NET C# MSSQL) where users are asked to register before payment (in case if they are not registered).

Whenever a user register, 1 table is created automatically using C#. The purpose of this table is to store data for Cart Items. I thought this would make the logic needed for Cart Items/table easier. Recently I realize the impact of this logic. At the moment I have like 735 users, which means 735 more tables. So the total count of my tables is 785 (including 50 tables I use for the whole website). Now it seems my website is getting slow and above that sometimes, when a user register, the cart table is not created. Due to this, there arises an unexpected error. Till now there are like 8 users for whom the cart table is not created. I had to manually create those.

My assumption is that, my website is getting slow due to the number of tables in my database.

Guys, please help me understand my problem and if possible give me advice or suggestions so that I may optimize my database and website. And is there a limit, like how many tables can be created per database?

Thank you for your time and concern.

Comment: Use a single [Cart] table for all Users.  Add a UserID column to the Cart table to distinguish the different rows for each User.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am thinking now but it's going to be a lot of work to enter all the data in each (735) table and I will have to change my coding as well but if that's the only way, then I must do that. I regret for not have for-seen that. In the mean time I would like to know the answer (if there is) of my questions. Thank you

Comment: You can write a SQL Server proc to copy all of the data at once from the user-cart tables to the common cart table..  Ask it as another question, and include the table definition of the user-cart tables (and their naming format).

Answer (score 2):

Use one "cart" table, storing all the cart items for all users in that table. Distinguish the different carts by making use of a cartID, that is bound to the specific user.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am thinking now but it's going to be a lot of work to enter all the data in each (735) table and I will have to change my coding as well but if that's the only way, then I must do that. In the mean time I would like to know the answer (if there is) of my questions. Thank you

Comment: You can easily write some code to automate the process. And yes, I guess your Database might be suffering a bit with 800 tables, taking this question into consideration, you might have made more bad design decisions that we don't know about also affecting it. Write some code to move the different carts into one table. Should actually be a quick job to move all the carts and make changes to your source to use it.

Answer (score 1):

That is poor database design.  You should (almost?) never have to create tables dynamically.  Create one "Cart" table and add a user id field.  Use that table for everybody.  Modify your queries to filter by user id.

There is not set limit on the number of tables.  You can have over 2 billion database objects:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Do invest the time to script out transferring data to the new single table... it will be worth it in the end.  There is tremendous overhead with your current approach (creating objects, permissions, indexing, optimizing, etc.).

Comment: Yes, that's what I am thinking now but it's going to be a lot of work to enter all the data in each (735) table and I will have to change my coding as well but if that's the only way, then I must do that. I regret for not have for-seen that. In the mean time I would like to know the answer (if there is) of my questions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the cart design is just **wrong**, and should be changed.

I strongly suspect that if you've gone for that "cart" design, this is indicative of (thinks how to put it nicely)... a level of experience that could have led you to make many other poor design choices.

The performance issue *could* be related, but without profiling there is no way to know for sure. Frankly, there are all kinds of ways to make a system slow. Consider using a tool like [mini-profiler](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/), which will help you understand what code is behaving slowly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and also for suggesting the mini-profiler. I will certainly try it out.

By the way, this was the first time I am building a huge website all by myself. I was given a time frame of 20 days to do the research as well as to build it. Lots of javascript, designing plus the whole of backend coding involved (the first time making cart). Due to the pressure I misjudge the approach (didn't have anyone to guide me).

If you have any more suggestions or tools I may need then please guide me. I really appreciate it.